# How to retrieve the value of an input in Angular 2 project without typescript

Tags: angular, ionic2

I can retrieve the value in the view but not in the construtor.
My component is in an ngFor and I want to edit each item **independently**. That's why I create a child component

```
 <li style="list-style-type: none;" *ngFor="let event of item.Events">
 ... <child-component [demo]="event"></child-component>
```

In the child component : 
I can display the result of demo in the view but I can not retrieve it in the constructor to be able to manipulate it

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    queries: {
        content: new ViewChild('content')
    },
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/dashboard/timeline/timeline-feeling/index.html',
    ...
    inputs: ['demo'],
    ...
})

export class TimelinFeeling{
    static get parameters () {
        return [];
    }

    constructor () {
        this.demo = demo;
        console.log(this.demo); //return undefined
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the property (TypeScript requirement) and decorate it with `@Input` (Angular requirement):

```
import { Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/dashboard/timeline/timeline-feeling/index.html',
    ...
})

export class TimelinFeeling{
    @Input() public demo = null;
    @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
    static get parameters () {
        return [];
    }

    ngOnInit () {
        this.demo = demo;
        console.log(this.demo); //return undefined
    }
```

Finally, check the value in `ngOnInit` instead.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I have this error with your solution : Syntax Error Unexpected token (31:18)

Comment: Okay, but did you use it as is? What line corresponds with (31:18) in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Input values are not yet set in the constructor. Use `ngOnInit()` instead:

```
ngOnInit () {
    console.log(this.demo); //return undefined
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I have this error with your solution : ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: demo is not defined

Comment: You should have the same problem in the code in your question. Not sure what the intention was for this line. I guess you can just remove it.

Comment: Glad to hear :)